# use scss class name to get already defined variable?

Tags: html, css, sass

Say you have repeating code:

```
$primary: white;
$secondary: black;
$success: green;
$danger: red;
$warning: yellow;

&.primary-stripe {
  border-top-color: $primary;
}

&.secondary-stripe {
  border-top-color: $secondary;
}

&.success-stripe {
  border-top-color: $success;
}

&.danger-stripe {
  border-top-color: $danger;
}

&.warning-stripe {
  border-top-color: $warning;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify it by using by accessing the variable based upon the already existing class name? For example

```
&.[var]-stripe {
   border-top-color: $[var];
}
```

The only tricky part would be what happens when $[var] doesn't exist. I guess then scss may error?

Comment: Would it be OK for you to create a map with all your colors ? If so, you could loop over the colors in your map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [SASS Map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) for this:

```
$color_map: (
'primary': 'white',
'secondary': 'black',
'success': 'green',
'danger': 'red',
'warning': 'yellow'
);


.main_selector {
   @each $name, $color in $color_map {
      &.#{$name}-stripe {
        border-top-color: #{$color};
      }
   }
}
```

This compiles to:

```
.main_selector.primary-stripe {
  border-top-color: white;
}
.main_selector.secondary-stripe {
  border-top-color: black;
}
.main_selector.success-stripe {
  border-top-color: green;
}
.main_selector.danger-stripe {
  border-top-color: red;
}
.main_selector.warning-stripe {
  border-top-color: yellow;
}
```